# KNN on collaborative filtering

Tags: recommender-system

After I calculated the similarities matrix, how do I get the neighbors, for example, consider the matrix of similarities between users, if I did not make any mistakes, the matrix must be symmetric with diagonal 1 considering pearson.

```
u0: 1.0  -0.2  0.8  -0.6  0.2
u1:-0.2   1.0  0.7  -0.3  0.4
u2: 0.8   0.7  1.0   0.4  0.3
u3:-0.6  -0.3  0.4   1.0  0.8
u4: 0.2  -0.4  0.3   0.8  1.0
```

So if I want get 2 neighbors for u0, the result would be `[u2:0.8, u4:0.2]`.

I didn't undertando why to do KNN and not a sort operation on its row?